# Why doesn't Mongo read the /usr/local/mongodb/mongod.conf file?

Tags: macos, mongodb

In my `/usr/local/mongodb/mongod.conf` file, I have

```
# Store data alongside MongoDB instead of the default, /data/db/
dbpath = /usr/local/mongodb_data

# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

But when I try to run Mongo (on my mac), I get an error:

```
Wed Sep 14 09:29:35 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist, terminating
```

So apparently the conf file is not being read

Comment: Did you start `mongod` with `--config`? The argument to `--config` identifies a configuration file to read at startup.

Comment: What's the default config file?

Comment: There is no default config file. You must either specify the options you want on the command line or specify a config file with either `--config` or `-f`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must specify if you want it to use another config; there isn't a default config file.

See Here:
[File Based Configuration](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration)

To achieve what you want to do; you can either specify your config path or start your mongo server like:

```
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/mongodb_data
```

Comment: According to the docs, `On some packaged installs of MongoDB (for example Ubuntu & Debian) the default file can be found in /etc/mongodb.conf which is automatically used when starting and stopping MongoDB from the service.` - so there IS a default for some installs. I assume for OS X too?

Comment: Not on OSX. It is on a few linux distro builds as they are maintained by the community not by Apple :)

Comment: OSX 10.10.2 found the default config file at: `usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: that is right @MattJensen, still, mongod does not use it for some reason. My current version of macOS is 10.14.2

Answer (score 31):

If you install MongoDB using [brew](https://brew.sh/), the LaunchAgent files that it generates for you will use a configuration file at /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf by default.

This behavior is defined in:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/mongodb.rb

Note that this "default" only applies when running MongoDB as a service via `launchctl`, not manually starting it by running `mongodb`.

As of 2015-03-09, the instructions given by Homebrew after installing MongoDB 3.0.0 are:

```
==> Caveats
To reload mongodb after an upgrade:
    launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

Note the explicit `--config` argument in the manual run command.

Comment: Also I have found my one will create a FILE called etc under /usr/local/ instead of the correct path. Moving the file to its correct location fixed this.

Comment: After updating to 2.6 that file doesn't seem to be used as default config anymore.

Comment: I just upgraded my mongodb to 2.6.0_1 via brew, and it certainly looks to me like the new /usr/local/opt/mongodb/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist is running mongodb with "--config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf".  What are you seeing, @Sloy?

Comment: @davidmc24 I didn't know where that default config file was set. That file that say out is pointing out to /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf, but that config is definitely not being applied when I run `mongod. I just changed my database folder to the default (/data/db) as a workaround.

Comment: Yes I confirm this, mongodb 2.6 doesn't use `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` by default

Comment: If you run mongod from the command-line, the LaunchAgent files created by Homebrew aren't used, and thus, it won't get a default `--config` argument from there.  See updated answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to just be able to type `mongod` and have it work decently.  This works, but with caveats:

```
% sudo mkdir /data
% sudo ln -s /usr/local/var/mongodb /data/db
```

Note that there are some useful configurations in homebrew's default /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf.  Here's the file for reference:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

So it'll log to the console, and connections won't be restricted to localhost.

Note: as in @ballPointPenguin's post, now that Homebrew has `brew services`, that is an excellent option.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @davidmc24, homebrew installation of mongo will use the configuration file by default when started with launchctl. Simply use:

```
brew services start mongodb
```

You can follow the logs at (default location):

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```